# Unable to delete jetty working directory before jetty starts or creates it's working directory

Tags: shell, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am kind of running into this interesting problem. I wanted to delete the jetty working directory before jetty restarts next time. The application has 2 war files and this is implemented using embed jetty. Name of the working folder looks like below:

jetty-0_0_0_0-10000-oaxui_war-_ui_oax-any-4214704288653178451

jetty-0_0_0_0-10000-oaxservice_war-_api_oax-any-1938823993160354573

Options 1: We have run.sh file which actually starts JettyServer.So I thought to place the below code in the file just before that.

```
echo "now deleting"
DELTEMP="rm -rf /tmp/jetty*"
exec $DELTEMP
echo "deleted....."


Result: It actually deletes the jetty working directory but does not let it create one working directory also.
```

Option 2: Create a temp directory in the location provided by us as below and then later delete this folder using the run.sh and above command but the path will be custom. Unfortunately, this also didn't help as the working directory was not being created in the first place.

```
private HandlerCollection getWebAppHandlers() throws SQLException, NamingException{
        //Setting the war and context path for the service layer: oaxservice
        File tempDir1 = new File("/faw/service/appshell/tempdir/");
        File tempDir2 = new File("/faw/service/appshell/tempdir/");
        WebAppContext serviceWebapp = new WebAppContext();
        tempDir1.mkdirs();
        serviceWebapp.setTempDirectory(tempDir1);
        serviceWebapp.setWar(APPSHELL_API_WAR_FILE_PATH);
        serviceWebapp.setContextPath(APPSHELL_API_CONTEXT_PATH);


        //setting the war and context path for the UI layer: oaxui
        WebAppContext uiWebapp = new WebAppContext();
        tempDir2.mkdirs();
        uiWebapp.setTempDirectory(tempDir2);
        uiWebapp.setWar(APPSHELL_UI_WAR_FILE_PATH);
        uiWebapp.setContextPath(APPSHELL_UI_CONTEXT_PATH);
        uiWebapp.setAllowNullPathInfo(true);
        uiWebapp.setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.dirAllowed", "false");

        //set error page handler for the UI context
        uiWebapp.setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler());

        //handling the multiple war files using HandlerCollection.
        HandlerCollection handlerCollection = new HandlerCollection();
        handlerCollection.setHandlers(new Handler[]{serviceWebapp, uiWebapp});
        return handlerCollection;
    }
```

Below is the complete JettyServer.java file

```
public class JettyServer {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JettyServer.class.getName());
    private static final int JETTY_PORT = 10000;
    private static final String JETTY_REALM_PROPERTIES_FILE_NAME = "realm.properties";
    private static final String JETTY_REALM_NAME = "myrealm";

    private static final String APPSHELL_WAR_FOLDER  = "/faw/service/appshell/target/";
    private static final String APPSHELL_UI_WAR_FILE_PATH = APPSHELL_WAR_FOLDER+"oaxui.war";
    private static final String APPSHELL_API_WAR_FILE_PATH = APPSHELL_WAR_FOLDER+"oaxservice.war";
    private static final String APPSHELL_API_CONTEXT_PATH  = "/api/oax";
    private static final String APPSHELL_UI_CONTEXT_PATH  = "/ui/oax";

    private static final String JETTY_CONFIG_FOLDER = "/faw/service/appshell/config/";
    private static final String JETTY_CONFIG_FILE = JETTY_CONFIG_FOLDER+"datasource.properties";
    private static final String JETTY_CONFIG_DATASOURCE_URL = "datasource.url";
    private static final String JETTY_CONFIG_APPSHELL_SCHEMA_NAME = "appshell.datasource.username";
    private static final String JETTY_CONFIG_APPSHELL_SCHEMA_PWD = "appshell.datasource.password";
    private static final String JETTY_CONFIG_APPSHELL_DS_INITIAL_POOL_SIZE = "appshell.datasource.initialPoolSize";
    private static final String JETTY_CONFIG_APPSHELL_DS_MAX_POOL_SIZE = "appshell.datasource.maxPoolSize";

    private static final String JETTY_CONFIG_FAWCOMMON_SCHEMA_NAME = "fawcommon.datasource.username";
    private static final String JETTY_CONFIG_FAWCOMMON_SCHEMA_PWD = "fawcommon.datasource.password";
    private static final String JETTY_CONFIG_FAWCOMMON_DS_INITIAL_POOL_SIZE = "fawcommon.datasource.initialPoolSize";
    private static final String JETTY_CONFIG_FAWCOMMON_DS_MAX_POOL_SIZE = "fawcommon.datasource.maxPoolSize";

    private static final int INITIAL_POOL_SIZE_DEFAULT = 0;
    private static final int MAX_POOL_SIZE_DEFAULT = 50;

    private static final String JNDI_NAME_FAWAPPSHELL = "jdbc/CXOMetadataDatasource";
    private static final String JNDI_NAME_FAWCOMMON = "jdbc/FawCommonDatasource";

    private static final String JETTY_REQUEST_LOG_FILE_NAME = "/faw/logs/appshell/applogs/jetty-request.yyyy_mm_dd.log";
    private static final String JETTY_REQUEST_LOG_FILE_NAME_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy_MM_dd";
    private static final boolean JETTY_REQUEST_LOG_FILE_APPEND = true;
    private static final int JETTY_REQUEST_LOG_FILE_RETAIN_DAYS = 31;
    private static final String JETTY_STDOUT_LOG_FILE_NAME = "/faw/logs/appshell/applogs/jetty-out.yyyy_mm_dd.log";

    private static final int MAX_REQUEST_HEADER_SIZE = 65535;

    private static final String SSL_SERVER_KEY_STROKE_PATH="/faw/tmp/customscript/certs/server.jks";
    private static final String SSL_TRUST_KEY_STROKE_PATH="/faw/tmp/customscript/certs/trust.jks";
    private static final String SSL_KEY_STROKE_KEY="changeit";

    public static QueuedThreadPool threadPool;

    public JettyServer() {

        try {


            //Redirect system out and system error to our print stream.
            RolloverFileOutputStream os = new RolloverFileOutputStream(JETTY_STDOUT_LOG_FILE_NAME, true);
            PrintStream logStream = new PrintStream(os);
            System.setOut(logStream);
            System.setErr(logStream);

            Server server = new Server(JETTY_PORT);
            server.addBean(getLoginService());
            //Set SSL context
            if (isIDCSEnvironment) {
                try {
                    logger.info("Configuring Jetty SSL..");
                    HttpConfiguration http_config = new HttpConfiguration();
                    http_config.setSecureScheme("https");
                    http_config.setSecurePort(JETTY_PORT);
                    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory.Server();
                    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(SSL_SERVER_KEY_STROKE_PATH);
                    sslContextFactory.setCertAlias("server");
                    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword(SSL_KEY_STROKE_KEY);
                    sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePath(SSL_TRUST_KEY_STROKE_PATH);
                    sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePassword(SSL_KEY_STROKE_KEY);
                    HttpConfiguration https_config = new HttpConfiguration(http_config);
                    https_config.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());
                    ServerConnector https = new ServerConnector(server, new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.asString()), new HttpConnectionFactory(https_config));
                    https.setPort(JETTY_PORT);
                    server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{https});
                    logger.info("Jetty SSL successfully configured..");
                } catch (Exception e){
                    logger.severe("Error configuring Jetty SSL.."+e);
                    throw e;
                }
            }
            Configuration.ClassList classlist = Configuration.ClassList.setServerDefault(server);
            classlist.addAfter("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration",
                    "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration",
                    "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration");

            //register oaxui and oaxservice web apps
            HandlerCollection webAppHandlers = getWebAppHandlers();

            for (Connector c : server.getConnectors()) {
                c.getConnectionFactory(HttpConnectionFactory.class).getHttpConfiguration().setRequestHeaderSize(MAX_REQUEST_HEADER_SIZE);
                c.getConnectionFactory(HttpConnectionFactory.class).getHttpConfiguration().setSendServerVersion(false);
            }

            threadPool = (QueuedThreadPool) server.getThreadPool();

            // request logs
            RequestLogHandler requestLogHandler = new RequestLogHandler();
            AsyncRequestLogWriter asyncRequestLogWriter = new AsyncRequestLogWriter(JETTY_REQUEST_LOG_FILE_NAME);
            asyncRequestLogWriter.setFilenameDateFormat(JETTY_REQUEST_LOG_FILE_NAME_DATE_FORMAT);
            asyncRequestLogWriter.setAppend(JETTY_REQUEST_LOG_FILE_APPEND);
            asyncRequestLogWriter.setRetainDays(JETTY_REQUEST_LOG_FILE_RETAIN_DAYS);
            asyncRequestLogWriter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
            requestLogHandler.setRequestLog(new AppShellCustomRequestLog(asyncRequestLogWriter));
            webAppHandlers.addHandler(requestLogHandler);

            StatisticsHandler statisticsHandler = new StatisticsHandler();
            statisticsHandler.setHandler(new AppshellStatisticsHandler());
            webAppHandlers.addHandler(statisticsHandler);

            // set handler
            server.setHandler(webAppHandlers);

            //start jettyMetricsPsr
            JettyMetricStatistics.logJettyMetrics();

            // set error handler
            server.addBean(new CustomErrorHandler());

            // GZip Handler
            GzipHandler gzip = new GzipHandler();
            server.setHandler(gzip);
            gzip.setHandler(webAppHandlers);


            //setting server attribute for datasources
            server.setAttribute("fawappshellDS", new Resource(JNDI_NAME_FAWAPPSHELL, DatasourceUtil.getFawAppshellDatasource()));
            server.setAttribute("fawcommonDS", new Resource(JNDI_NAME_FAWCOMMON, DatasourceUtil.getCommonDatasource()));
            //new Resource(server, JNDI_NAME_FAWAPPSHELL, getFawAppshellDatasource());
            //new Resource(server, JNDI_NAME_FAWCOMMON, getFawCommonDatasource());

            Map<String, String> configDetails;
            if (isIDCSEnvironment) {
                configDetails = DatasourceUtil.getConfigMap();
            } else {
                configDetails = DatasourceUtil.configMapInternal;
            }
            if (isIDCSEnvironment && configDetails.containsKey(PODDB_ATP_ENABLED) && BooleanUtils.toBoolean(configDetails.get(PODDB_ATP_ENABLED))){
                configDetails.put(DatabagProperties.LCM_MASTER_PROPERTY,"true");
                try {
                    DBUtils.migrateDBATP(configDetails, DatasourceUtil.getFawAppshellDatasourceATP());
                    configDetails.remove(DatabagProperties.LCM_MASTER_PROPERTY, "true");
                } catch(SQLException e){
                    logger.info("Exception while executing DBUtils.migrateDBATP.");
                    if(LCMUtils.isATPDBDown(e)) {
                        logger.info("Redis flow starts....Skipping consumption from Redis for now");
                    }
                    else{
                        logger.info("This is not eligible for redis flow. Actual Exception : "+ e);
                        throw e;
                    }
                }
            } else if (isIDCSEnvironment && configDetails.containsKey(PODDB_ATP_ENABLED) && !BooleanUtils.toBoolean(configDetails.get(PODDB_ATP_ENABLED))){
                try{
                    DBUtils.migrateDB();
                } catch (FawLCMPluginException e) {
                    logger.info(" This is not eligible for Redis consumption and exception is : " + e);
                }
            }

            //For Dev env..
            if (!isIDCSEnvironment && configDetails.containsKey(PODDB_ATP_ENABLED) && BooleanUtils.toBoolean(configDetails.get(PODDB_ATP_ENABLED))){
                configDetails.put(DatabagProperties.LCM_MASTER_PROPERTY,"true");
                try{
                    DBUtils.migrateDBATP(configDetails,DatasourceUtil.getDevFawAppshellDatasourceATP());
                    configDetails.remove(DatabagProperties.LCM_MASTER_PROPERTY,"true");
                }
                catch(SQLException e){
                    logger.info("Exception while executing DBUtils.migrateDBATP for dev environment.");
                    if(LCMUtils.isATPDBDown(e)) {
                        logger.info("Redis flow starts....Skipping consumption from Redis for now");
                    } else{
                        logger.info("This is not eligible for redis flow. Actual Exception for dev: "+ e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (!isIDCSEnvironment && configDetails.containsKey(PODDB_ATP_ENABLED) && !BooleanUtils.toBoolean(configDetails.get(PODDB_ATP_ENABLED))){
                try {
                    DBUtils.migrateDB();
                }catch (FawLCMPluginException e) {
                    logger.info(" This is not eligible for Redis consumption and exception in dev is : " + e);
                }
            }
            server.start();
            server.join();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private HandlerCollection getWebAppHandlers() throws SQLException, NamingException{
        //Setting the war and context path for the service layer: oaxservice
        File tempDir1 = new File("/faw/service/appshell/tempdir/");
        File tempDir2 = new File("/faw/service/appshell/tempdir/");
        WebAppContext serviceWebapp = new WebAppContext();
        tempDir1.mkdirs();
        serviceWebapp.setTempDirectory(tempDir1);
        serviceWebapp.setWar(APPSHELL_API_WAR_FILE_PATH);
        serviceWebapp.setContextPath(APPSHELL_API_CONTEXT_PATH);


        //setting the war and context path for the UI layer: oaxui
        WebAppContext uiWebapp = new WebAppContext();
        tempDir2.mkdirs();
        uiWebapp.setTempDirectory(tempDir2);
        uiWebapp.setWar(APPSHELL_UI_WAR_FILE_PATH);
        uiWebapp.setContextPath(APPSHELL_UI_CONTEXT_PATH);
        uiWebapp.setAllowNullPathInfo(true);
        uiWebapp.setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.dirAllowed", "false");

        //set error page handler for the UI context
        uiWebapp.setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler());

        //handling the multiple war files using HandlerCollection.
        HandlerCollection handlerCollection = new HandlerCollection();
        handlerCollection.setHandlers(new Handler[]{serviceWebapp, uiWebapp});
        return handlerCollection;
    }

    /**
     * The name of the LoginService needs to correspond to what is configured a webapp's web.xml which is
     * <realm-name>myrealm</realm-name> and since it has a lifecycle of its own, we register it as a bean
     * with the Jetty server object so it can be started and stopped according to the lifecycle of the server itself.
     *
     * @return the login service instance
     * @throws FileNotFoundException In case realmProps is null
     */
    public LoginService getLoginService() throws IOException {
        URL realmProps = JettyServer.class.getClassLoader().getResource(JETTY_REALM_PROPERTIES_FILE_NAME);

        if (realmProps == null)
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to find " + JETTY_REALM_PROPERTIES_FILE_NAME);
        return new HashLoginService(JETTY_REALM_NAME, realmProps.toExternalForm());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JettyServer();
    }
}
```

Run.sh file :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu  # Exit on error
set -o pipefail  # Fail a pipe if any sub-command fails.
VERSION=1.0

cd "$(dirname "$0")"
RED='\033[0;31m'
ORANGE='\033[0;33m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

function die() {
  printf "${RED}%s\n${NC}" "$1" >&2
  exit 1
}

function warn() {
  printf "${ORANGE}%s\n${NC}" "$1"
}

function info() {
  printf "${GREEN}%s\n${NC}" "$1"
}

CURR_PID=$$

mem_args=8192
info "mem args "$mem_args

export MAX_MEM=$mem_args
    #put the managed server specific variable setting below, then export the variables

    USER_MEM_ARGS="-Xms4096m -Xmx"$MAX_MEM"m -XX:MetaspaceSize=1024M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m"
    export USER_MEM_ARGS
    info "USER_MEM_ARGS= ${USER_MEM_ARGS}"

#FAW_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/faw/service/appshell/config/ucp_log.properties -Doracle.jdbc.fanEnabled=false $USER_MEM_ARGS -Xloggc:/faw/logs/appshell/applogs/gc.jetty.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XshowSettings:vm -XX:+PrintCodeCache -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512M -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=maxage=30m,defaultrecording=true,stackdepth=1024,dumponexit=true,dumponexitpath=/faw/logs/jetty/jetty_1618996595.jfr -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=4 -XX:GCLogFileSize=5M -XX:HeapDumpPath=/faw/logs/appshell_hprof-dumps_`date +%x_%r|awk -F" " '{print $1}'|sed  's/\//_/g'`.hprof"
FAW_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/faw/service/appshell/config/ucp_log.properties -Doracle.jdbc.fanEnabled=false $USER_MEM_ARGS -Xloggc:/faw/logs/appshell/applogs/gc.jetty.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XshowSettings:vm -XX:+PrintCodeCache -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512M -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder  -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=4 -XX:GCLogFileSize=5M -XX:HeapDumpPath=/faw/logs/appshell_hprof-dumps_`date +%x_%r|awk -F" " '{print $1}'|sed  's/\//_/g'`.hprof"

echo "now deleting"
DELTEMP="rm -rf /tmp/jetty*"
exec $DELTEMP
echo "deleted....."

info "FAW_JAVA_OPTIONS= ${FAW_JAVA_OPTIONS}"
if [[  -e "/faw/environment" ]]; then
sh /faw/tmp/customscript/setUpTLSCerts.sh
fi
CMD="java ${FAW_JAVA_OPTIONS} -cp /faw/service/appshell/target:/faw/service/appshell/libs/* oracle.biapps.cxo.docker.jetty.server.JettyServer --lib /faw/service/appshell/libs"
ulimit -c 0
# Now execute it
info "Executing: $CMD"
exec $CMD
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why are both temp directories the same path?

Comment: We can close this as the above suggestion helped to move forward.  Thank you Joakim, I will post the solution as soon as I find something specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you "Joakim Erdfelt" for the input. Got it. The below solution works fine for me in embedded jetty. I will be creating a custom delete method for deleting the directory first and then creating the jetty working directory.

```
public void cleanJettyWorkingDirectory(){
    final File folder = new File(JETTY_TEMP_WORKING_DIRECTORY);
    final File[] files = folder.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.matches( "oax.*" ));

    if (files!=null && files.length > 0) {
        for ( final File file : files ) {
            try {
                FileUtils.deleteDirectory(file);
                logger.info("Cleaning of the directory is completed.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.info("Unable to delete the Jetty working directory");
            }
        }
    }else{
        logger.info("No working directory file is present starting with oax for deletion.");
    }
}
```

Also while setting the war , we will do below to create directories:

```
       try {
            cleanJettyWorkingDirectory();
            logger.info("starting to create temp working directory for oax service ");
            java.nio.file.Path oaxServicePath = Files.createTempDirectory("oaxservice");
            String oaxServiceTempPath = oaxServicePath.toString();

            logger.info("starting to create temp working directory for oax ui ");
            java.nio.file.Path uiPath = Files.createTempDirectory("oaxui");
            String oaxUIServiceTempPath = uiPath.toString();

            File oaxServiceTempDir = new File(oaxServiceTempPath);
            File oaxUITempDir = new File(oaxUIServiceTempPath);
            serviceWebapp.setTempDirectory(oaxServiceTempDir);
            uiWebapp.setTempDirectory(oaxUITempDir);
            logger.info("The process of creating working directory is completed.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception while creating directories.",e);
        }
```